# C thread variable has values after declaration from nother thread

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I'm trying to do some simple things in C and I'm confused. 
The program is simple, the main function is handling thread according to a job que struct. Its opening up to 4 thread at a time. Around 300 threads till the end. The thread function is always the same but the args are different.

The hole code is bit long to paste here so I will paste some parts.

thread is opening as with the following parameter:

```
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED); 
pthread_create(&pth, &attr, dothejob, (void *) varis);
```

the thread called function

```
void *dothejob(void * varis){
unsigned char * arr1;
arr1 = (unsigned char*) calloc(3000000, sizeof (unsigned char));
unsigned char * arr2;
arr2 = (unsigned char*) calloc(3000000, sizeof (unsigned char));
// doing some calculations and comparisons and stuff
unsigned int topten[10];  
// <---- here topten has some values from previous threads, but why ? 
// picking top ten and putting it in the var topten[
free(arr1);
free(arr2);
pthread_detach(pthread_self());
}
```

If someone knows it please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: also: don't cast the return of `malloc`, that only hides potential problems, and `sizeof(unsigned char)` is by definition `1`.

Comment: So you create a detached thread (using `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED`) and then you detach the thread (using `pthread_detach`).  That does the same thing twice.  You don't need to call `pthread_detach` if the thread is already detached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write this inside a function:

```
unsigned int topten[10];
```

The array values are not initialized to `0`. They contain whatever happens to be in memory at location `topten` points to. It is undefined behaviour to use values from your `topten` array without writing your own new values into the array first. If you want your array to be filled with `0`s you should initialize it like so:

```
unsigned int topten[10] = {0};
```

Comment: it is filled with 0 in the first thread. I wanted to check its value and it sometime has negative and since it is unsigned the program crash.

Comment: @Prokop The fact that it is filled with `0` in the first thread is a pure coincidence. That is what happened to be in memory. It wasn't `initialized` to `0` though. You just can't use uninitialized values like that. If you want to initialize your array to `0` you can do it like this: `unsigned int topten[10] = {0};`

Answer (score 0):

`topten` is an *automatic array* and is allocated on the stack. In principle automatic variables are uninitialised and their content can be anything from what used to be on the stack earlier. Also by default, when you do not explicitly specify stack space for new threads, `pthreads` manages this space automatically and it could reuse stack space from already joined threads for new ones.

The first threads that you create get some freshly mapped memory for their stacks and that memory is zeroed by the operating system (or by the threading library). Later threads reuse this space and it is no longer zeroed.

Always initialise explicitly automatic variables and arrays!